# How to type 'spanning' symbol in latex

Tags: notation

Very simple question.

For a subring, submodule, subgroup, subspace of an appropriate object we often define them by the generators.

In this case we say subgroup generated by $x_1,\cdots x_n$ or $<x_1,\cdots x_n>$ except we don't quite use the inequality signs.

Could someone tell me how to type the notation for 'spanning'?

Comment: Do you mean $\langle x_1,\cdots x_n \rangle$?  That would be `\langle x_1,\cdots x_n \rangle`.  Also, for future reference [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html) may be useful to you.

Comment: You should ask these sorts of questions on TeX.SE, not here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`$\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n \rangle$` for $\langle x_1,\ldots,x_n \rangle$.

`$\left< x_1,\ldots,x_n \right>$` gives $\left< x_1,\ldots,x_n \right>$ and is marginally shorter to type -- but then the brackets will grow vertically if there are tall formulas between them, which may not always be what you desire.

Comment: exactly what I wanted. Now I think of it I used to know this notation but really couldn't find it. I will accept it when I can (apparently I need to wait)